# Get max with group by and other other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have created a sample table in dbfiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/QNWlduMl

I am trying to get the row with max value of column `cnt` along with all other columns including `Response` using `group by`.

Here's my attempt:

```
select 
     pid,
     propName,
     Address,
     City,
     Response,
     max(cnt) as response_count
from Prop
group by
     pid,
     propName,
     Address,
     City,
     Response
```

I don't need to `group by` `Response` but need to include it as I need it in the `select` clause.

Expected output:

```
pid propName    Address City    Response    response_count

1   p1  addr1   c1  3   30
2   p2  addr2   c2  4   60
```

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags

Comment: Your question needs to be stand alone so please include the sample data in the question (leave the fiddle its very useful).

Answer (score 3):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` to flag the row with largest `cnt` within each partition:

```
SELECT
    pid,
    PropName,
    Address,
    City,
    Response,
    cnt AS responseCount
FROM
    (
    SELECT 
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY
                pid,
                propName,
                Address,
                City
            ORDER BY
                cnt DESC
        ) AS cntRowNumber
    FROM
        Prop
    ) PropWithRowNumber
WHERE
    cntRowNumber = 1
;
```

Then just query that table to filter out everything but the top `cnt` rows.